# Exception when use EWS for create a appointment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am get a exception when use my service EWS, this is my code

```
public class ExchangeHelper
{
    ExchangeService exchangeService;

    public ExchangeHelper()
    {
        //Instantiate a new ExchangeService object
        exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        //Set the exchange WebService URL
        exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://hostname/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        //exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://hostname/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        //Set the credentials of the service to the credentials
        //that are associated with the impersonating account.
        exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                                        "user",
                                        "pass",
                                        "Domain.com"
                                            );

    }

    public void CreateAppointment()
    {
        var emailAddress = "user@doamin.com";
        //Set the ImpersonatedUserId property of the ExchangeService object to identify the impersonated user (target account).
        //This example uses the user's SMTP email address.
        exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress);
        exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, emailAddress);

        //create a new appointment object
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exchangeService);

        //set appointment properties
        appointment.Subject = "test";
        appointment.Body = "testBody";

        //In MSDN it says that if you dont specify the timezone, it will use the UTC timezone
        //but in reality it is not working that way.
        //so explicity setting the EST timezone


        appointment.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
        appointment.EndTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

        //add required participants
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(emailAddress);


        newFolder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);



         appointment.Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts, "emailAddress"));

         //Set it back to null so that any actions that will be taken using the exchange service
         //applies to impersonating account (i.e.account used in network credentials)
         exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = null;

         return the unique identifier that is created
         return appointment.Id.UniqueId;
     }
```

The exception is ***"The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user"***

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from your post whether the account you use for the credentials on the ExchangeService and for the ImpersonationUserId are the same.  If they are, then you would not need to use impersonation and should not set that property.  It seems like one *should* be able to impersonate oneself, but there's no need to do so, hence EWS may throw you back that exception.

If they are different, then it's pretty much as the message says: the account you use for the credentials must have the right to impersonate the user you set.  This typically involves some PowerShell magic by the Exchange admin to set this up.